# Looping through a list when KeyError occurs

Tags: python

I would like to know, how I can loop through a list when a `KeyError` occurs in python. The code is just representatively. In my real problem I want to loop through api keys (when the KeyError occurs use the next api key and do the request again). Imagine I have a list called `keys` but in my dict only the 3rd to 5th key works. I can easy jump to 2nd key if the first one doesn't work with my `try-except-statement` but how I can jump to the 3rd key if the 2nd doesn't work either?

I guess need something like a while loop, that loops until the `KeyError` occurs...

```
keys = ['key1','key2','key3','key4','key5']
keys_iter = iter(keys)


dict = {
"key3": "3",
"key4": "4",
"key5": "5"
}

try:
    print(dict[next(keys_iter)])
except KeyError:
    print(dict[next(keys_iter)])
```

Thankful for any help.

Aaron

Comment: You don't need to manually create an iterator.  All you need is `for key in keys:`  You also don't need to be manually calling `next`.

Comment: I guess you mean setting up this: ```for key in keys: print(dict[key])``` instead of the `try-except-statement`... But this doesn't solve the `KeyError`-Problem.

Comment: Right, if you expect missing keys, you can check the key's presence first, e.g. `if key in dict:`, or you can use a `try/except` block to catch missing key errors.  Or you can use `dict.get(key, default)` to supply a default value.  Etc. etc.  Also, you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name, since it masks the builtin.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']

my_dict = {
    "key3": "3",
    "key4": "4",
    "key5": "5"
}

for key in keys:
    key = my_dict.get(key)
    if key:
        print(key)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5']

check_dict_values = {
    "key3": "3",
    "key4": "4",
    "key5": "5"
}

for key in keys:
   if key in check_dict_values:
       //Do processing if success then call break else continue.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).